# Is there a way to fracture a mesh only by it's polygons?

Tags: mesh, add-on

I want the shards to be created not randomly, but by the edges of the polygons. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know with the Cell Fracture modifier you only have the option of splitting by mesh vertex, not face which is not exactly the same, but could yield approximate results.

Check the first option on the top left
[image]

[image]

Otherwise look into the *[Explode](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/simulate/explode.html)* modifier which uses particles to break an object by its faces

[image]